# Click-once application crashes after Form Load

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crash, clickonce

I saw this problem in several places on the internet, without any clear solution. I do need support to know how to detect the root cause and fix this problem for ever.

A ClickOnce application published and works on almost all computers, crashes after loading the startup form without any errors.

Crashes means -

1. 'Verifying application requirements' dialog box checks latest updates perfectly. In case there is, it downloads automatically.
2. Startup form opens for maximum 1 second, then closes automatically. [frequently] OR
3. Startup form opens, user types a letter (or clicks the mouse), then app closes automatically. [rarely]
4. No error message is thrown.

This phenomenon happens only on a limited number of computers, under specific user profiles. This means that on the same computer, the app launches without problem for user 'A', while for another user it crashes.

Already tried the following, without any solution -

1. Uninstall/reinstall the app - in most of the cases it works, but not always. Furthermore, it sometimes crashes when publishing new updates, on computers where the app was previously working.
2. Certificates - publishing the app with or without certificate does not make any difference.
3. Delete/Create user profile - did not solve the problem.
4. Manually delete the user profile folder from Documents And Settings/[user]/...
5. No Kensington mouse driver is avaliable on the computers.
6. Try/Catch blocks in Program.cs or in Startup form InitializeComponents()

Any idea where the problem is coming from, and how it can be detected?
Here is the code for Program.cs

```
namespace NCR_MaterialToolbox
{
    static class Program
    {

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
        {
            Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.ThrowException);
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new frmLogin());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for frmLogin

```
    public frmLogin()
    {
            InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Comment: I have installed MS Debug Diagnostic Tool, but it did not show me the reason why the app crashes.

Comment: I tried to add a FormClosing event handler to see the close reason, but the app crashes without running the FormClosing event... still nothing...

Comment: I installed VS 2010 express edition to the problematic computer to see if there is any missing reference/component. It runs perfectly in debug mode, but the published version still crashes... No more ideas...

Comment: Update #3
Added the following Prerequisities to the installation package -
Windows Installer 4.5 
Windows Installer 3.1 
.NET Framework 3.5 SP1 
Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64) 
SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 

No success.

Comment: Seems to be that something is wrong with the mouse. When updating the application to a new version, the Login form opens without any problem. However, if I click with my mouse, then after 1 sec, form closes automatically, and I never reach again my login form. However if I use the keyboard, it works.

Comment: I know this question is pretty old, for those who gets here researching like me, i want to share that i solved a similar problema killing process in the computer. To be more specific, i killed the "G-Buster Browser Defense".